# How to check for collisions between two tilemaps in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two tilemaps. One can be moved with WASD (tiles are instantly moved to their new location) and I want to detect when the tiles of this tilemap collide with the tiles of another tilemap.

Both have tilemapcollider2d and both are set to be triggers.

They both have scripts attached with:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Debug.Log("touching");
}
```

However it's never triggered and I have no idea why. Making one or both rigidbody2d's doesn't change anything either.

Comment: So i haven't worked with graphics much, but i recall that in college the way i would check for the collision between two simple 2D objects was comparing their X/Y coordinates. I assume a similar approach he could work where you can compare the new location of the tile moved and see if it hits one of the tiles?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tags on the colliding objects and compare for collision through the tags, like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.Tag == "tile"){
        Debug.Log("touching");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem: collisions are never triggered regardless.

Comment: did you put colliders on your objects?